# Does gravity actually have a ‘reaction force’?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, newtonian-gravity, momentum, conservation-laws

By (my limited knowledge of) Einstein’s theory of General Relativity, as gravity is not a force but rather the effect of an object’s inertial path following a geodesic through curved spacetime due to the mass of another object, would Newton’s Third Law still ‘apply’? Although gravity is not a force, does there exist a ‘reaction’ to it analogous to that of Newtonian gravity?

Comment: A geodesic is the trajectory of a "particle" in a particular spacetime.  The definition of a particle (much like dynamics of masses and charges in Newtonian mechanics or electrostatics) is an object that doesn't influence the existing field.  So, by definition, a particle exerts no influence on the spacetime.  But particles do not exist.  To get the actual spacetime dynamics, each object must be accounted for in Einstein's equation: each object changes the curvature of space.  In a Newtonian approximation to GR dynamics, these interactions could be seen as arising from Newton II, III and FG.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Newton's Law of Gravity consistent with General Relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89/)

Comment: this question and answers  discuss this, but it needs some mathematical knowledge to understand how Newtons law is consistent with general relativity https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89/

Comment: TLDR: Yes. It works both ways. If you toss a marble into the air, the segment of its world line that represents its flight is a geodesic that bends toward the Earth because of the Earth's mass/energy. At the same time, the Earth's world line bends towards the marble—Just not quite as much.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Actually, nobody has ever been able to demonstrate that particles in a two-body problem actually follow geodesics.  Approximately they do, sure, particularly when the mass ratio is very large.  But exactly, we don't know for sure.

Comment: @Buzz, OK, So, I used "geodesic" in an inappropriate way. But all I really wanted to say was that the marble's world line bends toward the Earth, and the Earth's world line bends toward the marble. Did I get that bit right?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/360930/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This was closed before I could post the answer I was working on. So I posted it to the linked question.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Physically, what you said is certainly just about right.  I just wanted to mention the mathematically interesting fact that the geodesic nature of particle motion for anything other than a test particle moving in a fixed background spacetime is actually a longstanding open problem.